# On submit: send data from one component to the other component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components. The one is only the form, the other one is the output of the form. Once the user hits the submit button, I would like to send data from the form component to the output component, .

This is what I have tried out:

**form.service.ts**

```js
  private listOfFoundedMatches;

  // Set list of founded matches
  setListOfFoundedMatches(value) {
    this.listOfFoundedMatches = value;
  }

  // Get list of founded matches
  getListOfFoundedMatches() {
    return this.listOfFoundedMatches;
  }
```

**form.component.ts**

```js
  constructor(private formService: FormService) {}
  onSubmit() {
     this.formService.setListOfFoundedMatches(data);
  }
```

This is how I try to receive the data:

**output.component.ts**

```js
  constructor(private matchResult: FormService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.matchResult.getListOfFoundedMatches());
  }
```

Fact is, I do receive the data but I receive them only once. What I want is to receive the data every time the user submits the form. How can I do this?

Comment: Emit an event to the parent component and from the parent component emit back to the child components

Comment: Option 2 is to create an observer in your server and subscribe to it. Every time you save your observer will action, next and your subscriber you catch it

Comment: No shortage of docs on choices for [component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Subject or BehaviorSubject (the difference is that BehaviorSubject always saves the last value).

**form.service.ts**

```
  private listOfFoundedMatches: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public listOfFoundedMatches$:Observable<any> = this.listOfFoundedMatches.asObservable();
  // Set list of founded matches
  setListOfFoundedMatches(value) {
    this.listOfFoundedMatches.next(value);
  }

  // Get list of founded matches
  getListOfFoundedMatches() {
    return this.listOfFoundedMatches.value;
  }
```

**form.component.ts** it's maintaince equals

```
  constructor(private formService: FormService) {}
  onSubmit() {
     this.formService.setListOfFoundedMatches(data);
  }
```

**output.component.ts**

```
  constructor(private matchResult: FormService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.matchResult.listOfFoundedMatches$.subscribe() {
       (listOfFoundedMatches) => {
              console.log(listOfFoundedMatches);
        }
    }
  }
```

With that, every time the user clicks the submit button, the FormService will fire an Observable event and the output.component.ts will get the last value emitted. Also if you want to get the last value saved you can call: formService.getListOfFoundedMatches().

Comment: I did not quite understand why an Observable can send the data but my version wouldn't. But anyway, it works great. Thank you!